# Java: type casting question

Tags: java, casting

Is there any way to do this in a single line:

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbSightName);
    tv.setText("Some Text");
```

I would like to do away declaring the intermediary tv, like so:

```
(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbSightName).setText("Some Text");
```

Not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but it isn't best practice

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbSightName)).setText("Some Text");
TextView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.lbSightName).setText("Some Text");
```

Comment: Thanks, why not best practice?

Comment: @Hein - You should prefer polymorphism / visitor pattern to instanceof/casting for dispatching in Java.

Comment: @Hein - see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326017/implementing-generic-interface-in-java/4326117#4326117 , wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) , and GoF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) for details

Answer (score 4):

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbSightName)).setText("Some Text");
```

Answer (score 2):

With one more set of parenthesis it should be possible:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbSightName)).setText("Some Text");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbSightName)).setText("Some Text");
```

Just add braces.

Answer (score 2):

Sure

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbSightName)).setText("Some Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

`((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbSightName)).setText("Some thingy");`

Adding one more set of parenthesis does the trick