# Realize a composition with generics and interfaces

Tags: java, generics, composition

I'm trying to realize the following:

My class X has a generic Y. This generic Y however needs to access resources of X and I'd like to handle this via interfaces in order to allow someone else to inherit from a arbitrary chosen class.

My current approach however results in a loop of generics:

```
public interface X<y extends Y<x extends X<y extends...>>> {

    Object getO();

}

public interface Y<x extends X<y extends Y<x extends ....>>> {

    void doSomething();

}
```

What I want to realize:

```
public class Goal<x X<y (this class)> implements Y {

    private final x minix;

    public Goal(x minix) {
        this.minix = minix;
    } 

    @Override
    public doSomething() {
        x.getO();
    }
}
```

How do I realize my goal without the common way of using an abstract class and the constructor implementation of the composition?

Comment: Could you give a bit of example code? Such things are hard to talk about without some "real meat" to it ...

Comment: It's hard to be certain about your exact requirement but perhaps the information found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326017/implementing-generic-interface-in-java could help you.

Comment: Done, added some detail as well.

Comment: Also, please do follow the Java naming conventions. Your code is unnecessarily hard to read when you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type parameters of your interfaces depend on each other. To resolve the recursion you have to introduce a second type parameter for each interface:

```
interface X<A extends Y<A, B>, B extends X<A, B>> {

    A getY(); //example    
    Object getO();

}

interface Y<A extends Y<A, B>, B extends X<A, B>> {

    B getX(); //example  
    void doSomething();

}
```

Goal class:

```
public class Goal<B extends X<Goal<B>, B>> implements Y<Goal<B>, B> {

    private final B minix;

    public Goal(B minix) {
        this.minix = minix;
    } 

    @Override
    public B getX() {
        return minix;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        minix.getO();       
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please show how you'd write the Goal class in this case? I sadly cannot really follow you there. Why would the addition of a second generic solve the problem?

Comment: @DellConagher I added an implementation of your Goal class.